# Google cloud gsutil fails inconsistently due to crcmode not compiled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-build, crc32

I'm running my build with google cloudbuild and I have a step that copies cached files from a google storage bucket.
 the step is using google's gsutil image from "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil".
the build runs automatically on every "push" to the github repo.
this is the step:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    id: 'Loading gradle cache'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        fileName=file.tar.gz
        if gsutil -q stat gs://cache_${PROJECT_ID}/${fileName}; then
          echo 'Gradle cache found'
          cd /
          gsutil -m cp gs://cache_${PROJECT_ID}/${fileName} ${fileName}
          tar -xpzf ${fileName}
        else
          echo 'Gradle cache not found'
        fi
    volumes:
      - name: 'gradle_cache'
        path: /root/.gradle
    waitFor: ['-']
    timeout: 60s
```

The problem is that sometime it passes and sometime it fails with the following due to crcmod not compiled:

```
CommandException:
Downloading this composite object requires integrity checking with CRC32c,
but your crcmod installation isn't using the module's C extension, so the
hash computation will likely throttle download performance. For help
installing the extension, please see "gsutil help crcmod".

To download regardless of crcmod performance or to skip slow integrity
checks, see the "check_hashes" option in your boto config file.
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

This error started happening 4-5 days ago.
any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See `gsutil help crcmod`. You need to install a compiled crcmod if you want to download composite objects. (It's also possible to disable checksumming instead, but that's a bad idea - you would not detect data corruption.)

Comment: I know, but the weird thing is that I'm using a built-in google image for gsutil from gcp cloud-builders. sometimes crcmod is compiled and sometimes it's not in the same image.

Comment: Is it possible that the cases where you don't get this error are for objects that were smaller than the parallel_composite_upload_threshold value set in your boto config file? In that case, the files would not be uploaded using parallel composite uploads, so when you try to download them gsutil doesn't need a compiled crcmod.

Comment: same file. when running automatically after push it fails but when triggering the build manually it passed. anyway, I fixed it by replacing the image it was using.

Comment: Hello, @UriAflalo, could you tell me which image you replaced it for to avoid the crcmod exception? I guess you workarounded the error by specifying a certain digest of gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil, rather than the default latest one. We are facing the same issue and I appreciate your any small help.

Comment: @RyoWakatabe, I actually tried to specify a specific version of gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil, but it's not possible. google is not tagging previous images.
instead I used google/cloud-sdk:300.0.0-alpine from dockerhub. you can also find it in gcr: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine. I use the alpine version because it's the most slim. gsutil works fine with it.